# How to clone DataBase in MongoAtlas to another Cluster?

Tags: mongodb, nosql, cluster-computing, clone

I'm creating a Homologation Server (to test new features) and I need to create a new DataBase for don't mess in the original DB (so I want to clone my original DB and use this one in my Homologation Server). I have already createded a new Cluster, and even downloaded a snapshot from my original DB. But I don't know how can I use this download in my new Cluster, or if has another way to clone the Database.

Comment: Did you check [mongodump](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongodump/) and [mongorestore](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongorestore/)?

Comment: I figured out that! with dump and restore, it works! Thanks :D